# How do I make a sticky rounded contact us button that opens up a menu with different contact methods in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, button, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am a beginner in WordPress. I would like to know how can you create this type of button, that sticks to the corner of all pages in your websites. I do not want a simple push to call button, I want this type, which opens up another menu. The button should be on all pages of my website and remain sticky on mobile and desktop.

This is what I want to implement in my website:

[image: Animated GIF of a WhatsApp button being clicked on from a random website]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, code wise?

Comment: I do not really know how to approach this as I never used wordpress before.